# How do i paginate with array.collect in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a collection of stories that user likes, i want to paginate it.

For that i tried to do: (in user controller)

```
@stories = @user.likes.paginate(page: params[:page]).map { |e| e.story}
```

But i got an error:
`undefined method 'total_pages' for #<Array:0x007f9548c4cdd8>`

on the partial:

```
<%= will_paginate @stories%>
```

(BTW, it works fine without paginating)
What do i do wrong here?

More information:

The connections between models:

User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :stories
  has_many :likes
end
```

Like Model:

```
class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :story
end
```

Story model:

```
class Story < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :likes , dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users , through: :likes, source: :users
end
```

Comment: Shouldn't you just be paginating the likes?  The actual stories would only be used in the view of page ____ of the likes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I heard some ways how to do that

But the best one is to add to the User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :stories
  has_many :likes
  has_many :liked_stories, through: :likes , source: :story
end
```

And in the controller

```
@stories = @user.liked_stories.paginate(page: params[:page])
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the code below just before calling paginate.

```
require 'will_paginate/array'
```

Answer (score 0):

The last part `.map { |e| e.story}` is the reason. Actually to use `will_paginate @stories` you need to have the `@stories` as `will paginate` object. But here you are getting just a simple array of `stories` where `total_pages` is not really unknown.

I didnt try the following but it will be somewhat like this

```
#FOLLOWING LINE MAY NOT WORK DIRECTLY!!
@stories = @user.likes(:include => :story).paginate(page: params[:page])
```

the point is `@stories` should have the output of `paginate` function. then `will_paginate` will work with the list.

**EDIT:** How about this.

```
@stories = (@user.likes.map { |e| e.story}).paginate(page: params[:page])
```

Actually i cant test it right now so just trying to figure it out based on my assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `map { |e| e.story}` you're throwing away the will paginate collection (which contains info such as which page are you on, total number of pages etc) and replacing it with a straight array.

Something like this should work:

```
likes = @user.likes.paginate(page: params[:page])
@stories = WillPaginate::Collection.create(likes.current_page, likes.per_page, likes.total_entries) do |pager|
  pager.replace likes.collect {|l| l.story}
end
```

This creates a new will paginate collection with the same metadata, but new contents.

Comment: whoops, had page instead of current_page